# Three div - arrange as table

Tags: html, css

I have three divs:

```
<div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
</div>

.one {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

.two {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}

.three {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}
```

But this not working good. I would like receive:

```
<table>
    <tr><td rowspan="2" class="one"></td><td class="two"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="three"></td></tr>
</table>
```

[LIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/7datp/1/)

How can i make it with DIV, same as with TABLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this.

One option is to use `display:table-cell` and related styling to get it to behave exactly as a table.

Another is to use `float` as you have but define the `width` of the container and use `clear` to position them as desired.

Here's a fiddle of the latter option: http://jsfiddle.net/adnrw/7datp/4/ with `padding` and `margin`s shown to match the `table` built in `cellspacing` and `cellpadding`

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer is to use CSS to display it as a table.**

You can use the following styles to achieve table layouts without HTML.

```
display: table;
display: table-cell;
display: table-column;
display: table-colgroup;
display: table-header-group;
display: table-row-group;
display: table-footer-group;
display: table-row;
display: table-caption;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, something like:

```
.one,.two,.three{
  width:100px; float:left;
}
.one{
   height:200px; background-color:red;
 }
.two{
   height:100px; background-color:green;
}
.three{
  height:100px; background-color:blue; clear:left;
}
```

Basically, just `clear:left;` on `.three`. To retain height on the container for all 3 `div`s you may want to add a `div` and `clear:left;` on it without floating.